# Building Apache log4cxx with CMake

Tags: cmake, mingw, msys2, apr, log4cxx

I am trying build Apache log4cxx 0.13.0 for mingw in windows platform

1. I builder and installed apr and apr-util using MSYS2
2. I downloaded log4cxx source from apache [repository](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4cxx/0.13.0/apache-log4cxx-0.13.0.zip)

but when configuring with CMake it shows this error:

```
CMake Error at src/cmake/FindAPR.cmake:17 (message):
apr-1-config --includedir failed with result %1 is not a valid Win32
application
Call Stack (most recent call first):
src/cmake/FindAPR.cmake:35 (_apr_invoke)
CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)
```

[CMakeOutput.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Uw3ye-zLr0hA_8p9dKkOlZPRBgTwjRS/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Do you have apr installed and `apr-1-config` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes I have it. Also I tried building my self apr and apr-util applying the mingw patchs and when I buil log4cxx I get the same error.  https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-apr

Comment: I actually have the same issue as you since log4cxx version 0.12.0. I am able to build version 0.11.0, see my recipe at: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/log4cxx.winlib

Comment: Scratch that, I got version 0.13.0 to build on Windows with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apu-1-config` of the apr-util package is actually a *nix shell script.

CMake is trying to run `apr-1-config` directly but of course Windows has no clue how to execute it.

The solution is execute `sh.exe` with `apr-1-config` (and its arguments) as argument(s).

The following patch fixes this issue for me:

```bash
patch -ulbf src/cmake/FindAPR.cmake << EOF
@@ -10,3 +10,3 @@
     execute_process(
-        COMMAND \${APR_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} \${ARGN}
+        COMMAND sh \${APR_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} \${ARGN}
         OUTPUT_VARIABLE _apr_output
EOF
patch -ulbf src/cmake/FindAPR-Util.cmake << EOF
@@ -11,3 +11,3 @@
     execute_process(
-        COMMAND \${APR_UTIL_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} \${ARGN}
+        COMMAND sh \${APR_UTIL_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE} \${ARGN}
         OUTPUT_VARIABLE _apr_output
EOF
```

I have updated [my winlibs build script](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/log4cxx.winlib) (which is mostly MSYS2 shell commands) so it now builds the most recent Apache Log4cxx 0.13.0. Besides this issue I had to add a few more workarounds though...

Comment: this is the correct answer to my question. I patched all the files as .wimlib and I was able to configure and generate the source using CMake. But make command dont find apr include path https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uGNsUOxnIGuav6bmr5_KPku6XnnYVwWO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I actually modifed `apr-1-config` in https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/apr.winlib because otherwise there were relocation issues.